# EB-3 (Green card) case in different county from the company's current address

Tags: united-states, california, immigration

I work for a `Marin County` based company as a foreign self-employed freelance contractor (software developer), and my client wants to open an office in `Los Angeles` and invited me to work there.

**How to start the case without a physical address in Los Angeles**? Should my boss rent an office first despite that he doesn't have anybody to sit in until I get the green card?

Comment: This belongs on [Expatriates.SE].  Why does the county matter?  It seems to me that a company could sponsor someone at their current address and then subsequently open an office elsewhere. Why would that pose a problem for the sponsored employee?  Once admitted to the country on an immigrant visa, he is a permanent resident and enjoys freedom of movement.

Comment: The county does matter, actually, it's very important. The wage depends on the location for example. Getting and holding green card doesn't provide God mode either, especially If I'll decide I want to go for the citizenship a couple of years later.

Answer (score -3):

Pick out a location then do the paperwork.

Comment: So we don't need a physical office/address? I know that I can't be home or remote worker because my profession (software developer) considered to be an office job, I might get auditing (+6-12 months processing) if the address is not an office's address.

Comment: I'm saying pick the physical address then do the paperwork for your EB-3.

Comment: I mean you could buy a building then get the paperwork done while the building is being made ready.

Comment: I see, my boss is a bit frustrated by paying $500-1000/month for a totally empty office for months, that's why I'm looking for something smarter solution, but it seems we don't have too many other things to do with this situation :)

Comment: You should be able to get it done faster than a few months. Call your local office.

Comment: Thank you, if you can elaborate your answer to be clear for the future users with referring links I can accept the answer as the best answer.